# Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] is null or empty

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-host, server-variables

This is an ASP.NET 2.0 website on IIS 7.5. Below is my global.asax. It has BeginRequest and a static method.
Does anybody see any issue with Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] being null or empty?

**Global.asax:**

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string host = GetHost(HttpContext.Current); //this is returning null;
}
public static string GetHost(HttpContext context)
{
        if (context == null) return null;
        string httpHost = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpHost)) return null;
        string hostName = httpHost.Split(new char[] { ':' })[0];
        return hostName;
}
</script>
```

This works fine on local box and test server which is IIS 6 but not on production which is IIS 7.5.

Added debugging info and found it's the ***string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpHost)*** statement that is returning null.
When I look into Firebug I see Request Headers show the Host is set as expected.

Any ideas?

**Note:** I will ty moving the code in GetHost directly in BeginRequest but for now just looking for some explanation of the current behavior

**Update:** I tried to access it the Page_Load of on of the page and I get the proper value. So it has to do something with may be Global.asax or not sure what else.

Comment: Instead of HttpContext.Current, does base.Context return anything different?

Comment: @Josh I will try that probably on Monday but I wonder why would that matter to HTTP_HOST?

Comment: Here you can find more about your problem: [Request.ServerVariables](http://mvolo.com/iis7-integrated-mode-request-is-not-available-in-this-context-exception-in-applicationstart/)

Comment: @Cerveser I am using it in the Begin_Request and it is not erring out on Request object but it's the Host ServerVariable being empty.

Comment: Do you run it in IIS7 on .NET 2.0 Classic mode? Maybe you should set the Enable 32-bit applications to true in the Application Pool.

Comment: @Cerveser nope it is running under Integrated Mode. I have been testing it on my local IIS 7.5 as well and it is working fine under 2.0 Integrated Mode.

Comment: any difference in the web.config? or a rewrite rule?

Comment: @Cerveser nope no url rewrite...and no web.config change except the connection strings.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to try Application_AcquireRequestState instead of Application_BeginRequest.

All Session "features" are available on that event and runs for each request too.

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string host = GetHost(HttpContext.Current);
}
public static string GetHost(HttpContext context)
{
        if (context == null) return null;
        string httpHost = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpHost)) return null;
        string hostName = httpHost.Split(new char[] { ':' })[0];
        return hostName;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I will try that but what I want to know is why is it working on local box and test server(IIS 6) but not on production(IIS 7.5).

Comment: IIS6 and IIS7 don't work exactly the same. So far I can tell the behaviour regarding the ussage of the global.asax should be the same, but sometimes is not.
Maybe if you are running the application in IIS 7.5 in integrated mode and in IIS 6 in classic mode, that would be an explanation.

Comment: It also works fine on my local IIS 7.5. There is something else into play which I cannot figure out. Similar code in another application is working fine though.

Answer (score 1):

To get the HOST name use this instead:

> HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host